# Anticipating values for functions

Tags: javascript

So I am writing a piece of code were one function does some scaling and returns an array of two scaling factors - those are needed in a different function. The problem here is that I do not want to call the function from with in the function for ease of debugging and understandability. So how do I transfer these two entries to to other function?
In terms of code it would look like so:

```
function1(param1,param2){
   //do some confusing math
   var Scale=[Scale1,Scale2];
   return Scale
}
funtion2(Scale[0],Scale[1],paramA,paramB){
   //some different stuff happens here, say:
   var Q=Scale[0]*paramA;
   var Z=Scale[1]*paramB;
}
...
//some time later funtion1 and function2 are executed
```

I hope the example cleared it up. Also the Project to this code is not complete and may be used for educational purposes - hence the isolation of the function.

Comment: "*I do not want to call the function from with in the function for ease of debugging and understandability*" I don't understand... Calling one function from another should be *the easiest* path here.

Comment: This actually seems to make no sense, can you elaborate on what you're trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

What I understand, you would simply call the first function and return the data. Then pass that data to the second function.

```
function CalcScale(param1,param2){
   //do some confusing math
   return [Scale1,Scale2]
}

function processScale(scale_1,scale_2,paramA,paramB){
   //some different stuff happens here, say:
   var Q=scale_1*paramA;
   var Z=scale_2*paramB;
}

scaling = CalcScale(param1,param2)

processScale(scaling[0],scaling[1],paramA,paramB)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function fn1(param1,param2){
   //do some confusing math
   var Scale=[Scale1,Scale2];
   return Scale
}
function fn2(scale_1,scale_2,paramA,paramB){
   //some different stuff happens here, say:
   var Q=scale_1*paramA;
   var Z=scale_2*paramB;
}

fn2(...fn1(param1,param2), paramA,paramB)
```

Comment: I doubt using ES6 is a problem today. Why would it be?

Comment: for browser support. It's all some culprits like IE which demands us to use ES5 and below or use BABEL to covert the code. just mentioned it in case the person wasn't aware.

Comment: I hope that no web developer here still has to work with IE in the modern day and age, but I guess they may.

Comment: Some Companies still support their website for IE, so developers had to follow what company instructs lol

Answer (score 0):

I hate to say it, but the problem seems poorly defined, but at this point, I would just suggest using a "global" variable.

```js
const Scale = [ 0, 0 ];

function function1(param1, param2) {
    // ...
    // update Scale and return the array
    return [
        Scale[0] = Scale1,
        Scale[1] = Scale2
    ];
}

function funtion2(paramA, paramB) {
    // ...
    // pray that function1 was called first, and use the results
    const Q = Scale[0] * paramA;
    const Z = Scale[1] * paramB;
}
```